# Binance API and Unity. Game involving depositing crypto and withdrawal

Tags: transactions

Hi if i need to allow players do deposit x crypto in my game. Use this deposited crypto and convert it to BUSD and use this as "token"to play games. And after winning, you can earn reward that will increase the amount you have and can be withdrawn in any crypto you want. How can i do this? I am using unity and binance api

Comment: I would advise against using BUSD or anything Binance affiliated right now as they are very likely under a liquidity crunch and in general have not been able to back up a lot of significant funding numbers on their platforms.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mX-luVDxCg
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ca-hQ4rjAQ

Comment: They also generally rely on over-leveraged "altcoins" getting liquidated (users losing their investment) for income, overall sketchy platform IMO.

Comment: Also as @Saxtheowl has mentioned it is not Bitcoin related AT ALL so if you do intend to use their shady products you should discuss it on a message board dedicated to that specific protocol ( if such a thing exists ).

Answer (score 1):

you are talking about BUSD which is a stabble coin that are not linked to bitcoin, you should see which blockchain use BUSD and how to use it, or better check the lightning network which is a bitcoin second layer which will allow what you want to want with BUSD but using bitcoin